# Installing KeystoneJS Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, keystonejs

Getting this error when trying to install KeystoneJS on DigitalOcean MEAN stack.

Getting this error: http://paste.ee/p/q1RmU
Using this command: sudo yo keystone (installed Yeoman)
Following this guide: http://keystonejs.com/getting-started/

Comment: Looks like you don't have root access on DigitalOcean

Comment: @JoeFitter I'm using the root user...

Comment: Since you're already the root user you don't need to prefix commands with `sudo`. However, I would strongly encourage you to use a non-root user for your keystone app. I would check the path/permissions for `~/.config/configstore` (if the directory exists); the error suggests the path either doesn't exist or is read-only.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your running into a permissions issue with Yeoman. It is best practice to not use `sudo` for things like this.

I would suggest creating a user for keystone, logging in as that user, and following [these](https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/master/npm-global-without-sudo.md) instructions for 'globally' installing a npm module for a user. Essentially, you will setup a `npm_packages` directory for the user and add it to your path.

Once you've done that you can install yeoman as this user, and without sudo. This should allow you to install keystone okay. I know it seems like a lot of work, but this is the best way to securely set up a node app on a linux box.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to KraigH. But An alternet way to get rid of this issue is  changemod for whatever it complains.
I listed all possible dirs here.

```
chmod -R g+rwx  /root /root/.config /root/.config/configstore /root/.npm
```

I tried to do what other says. that is to not use sudo. but it don't help.

Answer (score 0):

I normally build a Docker image and deploy it behind a nginx reverse proxy